# Coffeescript JS version?

Tags: coffeescript

If I am going to develop using Coffeescript I will need to know what browsers are supported by the coffeescript JS code - I'm sure there will be a webpage somewhere on the subject :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CoffeeScript's motto is "It's Just JavaScript." That means that if you write CoffeeScript code that invokes a feature that only exists in newer browsers, the JavaScript output will depend on that feature. CoffeeScript's own syntactic features, such as class inheritance and array comprehensions, generate code that's compatible with all major browsers going back to IE6.

Comment: Thanks Trevor, the only thing holding me back was the thought that the generated code might not be compatible with older browsers.  I guess I have a few hours work to get CS up and running but things should be more fun from then on :)

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** I now realize you were specifically asking for browsers which support the Coffeescript compiler. I have no detailed information about that, but considering the wide usage of Coffeescript my answer would be most of them.

No browsers support Coffeescript directly, although there may be some magic javascript snippets available that could compile Coffeescript to Javascript on the fly when a browser loads the page.

The usual workflow however is to compile Coffeescript to Javascript, and then only feed the browsers the resulting Javascript files. "Compile" may not be the proper word either, as it is more or less translating one set of source code (Coffescript) to another set of source code (Javascript), which is then parsed and sometimes JIT-compiled to execute in the browser (Spidermonkey, V8 etc).

Comment: *The core compiler however, does not depend on Node, and can be run in any JavaScript environment, or in the browser*, says the website. No need to precompile or have any magic JavaScript snippets.

Comment: Yeah, which is why I referred to it as "some magic javascript snippets". But if you like your pages loading slowly, be my guest. :-)

Comment: If that loads slowly, I don't know what prehistoric browser you are using. :P

Comment: @Radek'daknok'Slupik: yeah, and no one in the world needs to do asset caching or precompilation of anything! (Your view is myopic.)